# How to rewrite/transpose cells upon conditions?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose

I am trying to do some transposed mathematics in Google Sheets like so:

- content of cell A1 = 9:00 (formatted as time)
- content of cell B1 = EMPTY cell (formatted as time)
- content of cell C1 = text "Holiday" (formatted as time)
- content of cell D1 = 13:45 (formatted as time)

if A1 contains number `9` or `13` write in cell A2 `7:45` (all cells in sheet are formatted as time) and if A1 is EMPTY or contains text `Holiday` leave A2 EMPTY.

Same rule set for B1 > B2, C1 > C2 and D1 > D2 and then sum cells A2, B2, C2, D2 as "duration of time" in E2 like `=sum(A2:D2)`.

Example:

```
     A     B      C        D       E
1  9:00        Holiday   13:45
2  7:45                   7:45   15:30
```

so far all my effort gives me #ERROR!s and #VALUE!s.

is there some way to make it happen?

EDIT:

I did few experiments with this string but no luck so far:

```
=IF(B2="5:00",SUBSTITUTE(B2, "5:00", "7:45"), IF(B2="9:00",SUBSTITUTE(B2, "9:00", "7:45"),IF(B2="13:45",SUBSTITUTE(B2, "13:45", "7:45"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(if((C4:AG4)=1;;if(C4:AG4="";""; 
 (iferror(if(search("5:00";C4:AG4);1);
  iferror(if(search("13:45";C4:AG4);1);
  iferror(if(search("D";C4:AG4);1);)))))))
```

...I solved this with side calculations using an array formula, time duration conversion, and few sums

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to create an `onEdit()` trigger https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(/*check the the specific cell(s) of interest*/){
    //implement your logic
  }
}
```

Iv'e used triggered successfully in the past on google spread sheets.

Comment: @JudgeDredd this is one approach but you can probably accomplish what your asking using equations in the spreadsheet, if you include the exact approach you are attempting we could help you work on that.

Comment: well here is the sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14MQiQqej24TBu_pUwzY2i2spoD9cb2GyK87m-_MCZn0/edit#gid=0

Comment: and as i mentioned I would like to automatize it in a way like, if I write "5:00" in B2, I need "7:45" to be placed in B7 cell (also edited my post)